# Kick a single user out of the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I've seen multiple answers about kicking all of the other users but is there a way to stop the process id and kick just one user out of the database. Eg. user A B and C are connected to the database trying to generate reports but I only want C to stop and disconnect while A and B are still able to continue with their processes.

Comment: Don't sure what exactly you mean by "kick out". One thing that you can do is query sys.dm_exec_sessions, kill all queries of this login and disable it, but why don't disable it from the first place?

Comment: A and B are apps normally running to download reports. C is a new app that could be downloading bigger amounts of data depending on what it's doing so we would want to stop it when there's a problem in the server and would like the other 2 apps to be able to continue without problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a one-off you can use `EXEC sp_who` or `EXEC sp_who2` or similar to find the SPIDs of that user's connections and then use `KILL <SPID>` to stop them. Be aware that any transactions they have open in which changes have been made will need to be rolled back which could potentially take some time and be I/O intensive, but if they are just running reports the effect of this should be minimal. To stop them immediately restarting the processes disable their access *before* doing this (using `ALTER LOGIN <name> DISABLE` or by adjusting their access rights more granularly).

If you find yourself needing to do this regularly you could write a procedure to automate the task, so you could just run `EXEC kick_user_off '<name>';`, though if you need to do this sort of thing regularly enough for it to be worth the effort automating then I suspect you have a process and/or user problem that needs fixing of which this is just a symptom.

Comment: I had a procedure that took a database name rather than user names, but this approach works best.